# Is "...the name of the man to whom I talked on the phone" correct?

Tags: who-whom

**Question**

> I don't remember the name of the man _______ I talked on the phone

**Answers**

1. who
2. whom
3. to whom
4. to who

I think it's not correct to use `who` in the above sentence because the second part of the sentence is missing a `to` after `I talked`

I think it's also correct to say

> I don't remember the name of the man **who** I talked **to** on the phone

Could someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly right, or entirely right, depending on who(m) you ask.

> I don't remember the name of the man who I talked on the phone

Is incorrect.  That use of *talk* requires a preposition. It could be *to*, *with*, *about*, *over*, etc. "The man who I talked" is incorrect.

In your reasoning about the answer, you ignored the possibilities with *whom*. To people who are strict about English grammar, the correct answer must contain *whom*, because it's the object, not the subject in that sentence.

Many English speakers have decided this rule isn't important, and don't use *whom* at all. For them, the correct answer would be the one you gave: "...the man who I talked to on the phone."  Other English speakers sometimes use *whom*, but don't remember the exact rules; they might remember that we often use *whom* when it follows a preposition. For those people (and for the strict grammarians) the correct answer is 3, "to whom."